# Story about a girl who befriended a dragon

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I'm looking for a book that I read as a young teen before 1992.

It was a series.  I don't think it was the Pern series.

The dragons were hatched and the people lived by the sea. The main character was a girl. I want to say she lived in a cave and found a nest of dragons and befriended one.

The cover is in blues and has a dragon flying on front.

I for the life of me can't remember the title or author. It was a small paperback.

Comment: This is very vague (I mean, dragons, hatching and living by the sea describe dozens of series). You'll need to add as many details as you can, or this is very likely to get closed and deleted

Comment: Well I'm sorry I'm just trying to remember the details. It was over 20 years ago.  The main character was a girl.  I want to say she lived in a cave and found a nest of dragons and befriended one.  The cover is in blues and has a dragon flying on front.  I realize this describes a lot of books but I've searched and searched and can't find it

Comment: That certainly sounds like a Pern book- Dragonsong.
https://www.librarything.com/work/3391052/covers

Comment: I'll check it out.  I only remember 3 books in the series.

Comment: this might be it  I was focusing on dragonflight.  But after reading the plot for dragonsong, it's sounding familiar

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Dragonsong.  My wife loves the Harper trilogy in Pern, so I know it fairly well.

Comment: I would also agree with Dragonsong.  There are 20+ books of Pern stories now.  @Frock, you should write it up as an answer.

Comment: For final confirmation, check out the [cover of _Dragonsong_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW9pA.jpg).

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I believe that it is it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I realize you don't think the book is from the Pern series, but I really think this might be [Dragonsong](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28541.Dragonsong).  It is a small paperback, and part of a spinoff series, actually - which may explain why it didn't "feel" like part of the main series.

In any case, the story has a main character, a girl, who was from a sea-hold.  Descriptions include fishing and gathering along beaches, for extra emphasis.  There are dragons (and they hatch) in the series, but the book is more concerned with the dragons' little cousins, fire-lizards.

The main character finds a nest of the fire lizards, originally helping the queen and later returning there to wait out a dangerous storm, after running away because she wanted to be a Harper, which wasn't allowed.  In any case several fire lizards (nine, not one) imprint on her when they hatch, and stay with her throughout the book as she ends up studying to be a Harper anyway.

The cover I recall is blue, with sea and sky in the background and some rock formations.  The front cover has several fire-lizards surrounding a girl, the back cover does have dragons flying in.

[image: the cover I saw]

There are a couple other covers, I added a few which have one dragon on the front, and a blue background, if one that is a better match to your description might spark your memory

[image: Once cover][image: Another cover][image: third cover][image: last cover]

Comment: Yes it didn't seem like it fit in with the other series but after reading the whole description on Wikipedia I think I have finally found it.  Thank you everybody for your help.

Comment: I'm gonna pick up the book tomorow.  I'm very excited to re read this after about 25 years.

Comment: Glad you found it :)

Comment: There are 2 sequels-Dragonsinger and Dragondrums.

Comment: Not to mention that the main character becomes a major player on Pern.  As long as it's a book by Anne alone, she's probably in it somewhere.

Comment: Dragonsong and Dragonsinger are my favourite Pern books, possibly because I'm a musician. I could have read unlimited accounts of Menolly's life.