# Novel about small dragons which have power over fire or water; they become your friend if they hatch for you

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons

Small dragons, each have different powers, over fire, or water, if I remember correctly. You don't own them, but when they hatch for you, they are your friend and tend to stick with you. It was a full length book, possibly a series. I read it possibly pre 2010.

Comment: This is quite terse at the moment so could you try and [edit] in anything else you may remember? See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) for help. For example, do you know when you read this? Do you know anything that happens in the story? Was this a novel, novella, short story, etc.?

Comment: I wonder if you're thinking of the [fire lizards from Anne McCaffrey's Pern novels](https://pern.fandom.com/wiki/Fire_Lizard). These will imprint on you if you're there when they hatch. However they don't have any special powers beyond a basic form of telepathy.

Comment: John, sadly, that is not it. thank you for that suggestion! I am currently reading the Pern series though! its a great read.

Comment: I know you don't think it's _Pern_, but can you check out [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/164323/19561)? It's a spin-off of _Pern_ and seems to fit.

Comment: SQB thank you, but that isnt it. I know it is a very broad topic and a vague description.

Comment: Swamp dragons from the Discworld books?

Comment: Organic Marble, just looked that up, that is not it. Thank you,

Comment: sadly, not much. i believe there may have been an older man helping a young boy learn what to do with the dragons.